# How to tell if user's email address has been verified using Django, allauth, rest-auth and a custom user

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, email-confirmation

I'm using Django 2.0.10 with rest-framework, rest-auth and allauth. I have a custom user model.

I've got email verification working by using the allauth view. The verification email is sent when a user registers. If I click the link in the email, I'm taken to a page with a button to click to verify the email. This all works without error. However what I can't find out is what this actually *does*. No field in the user's data seems to change.

The behaviour I want is for users to be able to register and login, but only to be able to add content to the site after they have verified their email.

Edit: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621730/allauth-verified-user) gives part of the answer but doesn't say how to save the verification status as a property of the user so that you can check it in the front end when you load the user data.

settings.py

```
# django rest auth
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
```

api/urls.py

```
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', confirm_email,
     name='account_confirm_email'),
...
]
```

users/models.py

```
import uuid 

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.http import int_to_base36

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})

ID_LENGTH = 12

def pkgen():
    from base64 import b32encode
    from hashlib import sha1
    from random import random

    pk = int_to_base36(uuid.uuid4().int)[:ID_LENGTH]
    return pk

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=ID_LENGTH, default=pkgen, editable=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

When a user logs in, how can I find out if they have verified their email address? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Simplest solution would be to set `user.is_active` to `False` when you send an email confirmation to the user upon registration. And set the `user.is_active `  to `True` when he/she confirms the email.  Also before a registered user without an confirmed email tries to login you check to see if that user has `is_status`.. `True` or `False`. If its `False` then you don't allow them to login.

Comment: Thanks, but I want users to be able to log in immediately, just not create content. One reason is so that they can request a new verification email, for example if it didn't arrive or they lost it in spam.

Comment: Then you can simply add an extra field of type boolean in their profile namely `verified` and then set it to `True` or `False` based on if they have confirmed the email. You can then use this information to not allow them to edit the content.

Comment: Can you explain please how I would do that? I am happy to change my code but I don't want to rewrite the allauth code.

Comment: That post is where I got the information how to check the email address's status, but it doesn't explain how you would change the user object when the email address is verified?

Comment: But you haven't included it in your question. You should have included the link to that question. And then explaining why doesn't it help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187678/discussion-between-little-brain-and-ahtisham).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aha! Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621730/allauth-verified-user) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809505/django-allauth-how-to-properly-use-email-confirmed-signal-to-set-user-to-active), I think I have an answer.

The email address's status is saved in a separate table EmailAdress, not as part of the User model. This can be accessed in a modelviewset as follows:

api.py

```
from allauth.account.admin import EmailAddress

class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        # can view public lists and lists the user created
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            print('is there a verified email address?')
            print(EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, verified=True).exists())

            ...
```

This will return True if the user has any verified email address.

However, it's much more useful to add the verification status to the user. This can be done with a signal as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809505/django-allauth-how-to-properly-use-email-confirmed-signal-to-set-user-to-active).

views.py

```
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(email_confirmed)
def email_confirmed_(request, email_address, **kwargs):
    user = email_address.user
    user.email_verified = True

    user.save()
```

Now in api.py you can check like this:

```
print(self.request.user.email_verified)
```

This works if you have a single email address that can't be changed or deleted. If you allow multiple email addresses I guess you'd need to make more checks and update the user's status accordingly. But I have only a single email address which is used for login, so I think that's OK.

I think it would be better practice to make 'email_verified' part of a user profile, but this is a working demo.

Answer (score 7):

There's a function for this.

Syntax:

```
from allauth.account.utils import has_verified_email
has_verified_email(user, email=None) -> bool
```

According to the [source code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/fde96e6e7da6bbfd9faffaa90d75e6c3e7c2cc41/allauth/account/utils.py#L123) this does the same thing as what the accepted answer does when `email` is `None`. Otherwise it checks if the user has that verified email.

Comment: better answer than accepted answer as it re-uses allauth's own code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was able to solve this by using the code below:

```
#Project-level folder urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView, EmailVerificationSentView 
#These ConfirmEmailView, EmailVerificationSentView are very important
#I used other allauth/ dj-rest-auth views and they didn't automatically verify the email.

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('dj-rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/<str:key>/',
    ConfirmEmailView.as_view()), #This is at the top because apparently won't work if below. #Integral to problem solution

path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
path('api-auth', include('rest_framework.urls')),

 path('dj-rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/', 
  EmailVerificationSentView.as_view(),
        name='account_email_verification_sent'),#Integral to problem solution

]
```

The code above allowed me to create new users with the registration url. After which are sent an email with a link. When users click on the link they are redirected to the login page, with their email now verified in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

The official example:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```