# How can i restrict a django template to certain user categories?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I'm building a Django site where a user can register and do some stuff. After registering, the email should be confirmed.

Here is how a user is confirmed: in my database, i added a table called `account_emailaddress`. The `verified` column, in this table, will give `0` when the email address is not confirmed and `1` when it is confirmed.

Now, i have a template, this template should throw an error when the email address is equal to `0`.

Is this doable at all? I don't know where to put my feet to do this, so can someone guide to me an approach to do this? I'm not using a custom user model edited by me, but the Django user model.

Here is what the template looks like:

I'm assuming i need to sort this in my template's file, by adding an if statement like the one below:

```
{% block content %}
{% if email_is_confirmed %}
<style>

</style>

<body>

<p> CONFIRMED </p>

<div> <p>Here goes a bunch of features</p> </div>       



</body>

{% else %}

<p> Your email is not confirmed </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how your `account_emailaddress` table is linked to your user, whether it has a foreign key to the user table, or a column of an email address. I'll assume it's a one-to-one linked to the user. In which case, in a template, you can access the logged in user's object as `user`, and access the linked table as with any Django lookup, so e.g. `user.account_emailaddress.verified` (or whatever you have set the `related_name` to). In the template that would be:

```
{% if user.account_emailaddress.verified %}
```

You might also want to investigate packages such as `django-verified-email-field` or `django-user-accounts`.

Comment: Hey! To handle the registration part i'm using Django-Allauth. I already tried your solution, but i always get the error 'email not confirmed', even when the email IS confirmed, so there must be some logical error somewhere

Comment: Right, okay, that information would have been very useful to know first! :) That makes it very different, because one user can have multiple email addresses with allauth and then you don't know if any/all are verified. You want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467321/how-to-tell-if-users-email-address-has-been-verified-using-django-allauth-res and associated answers.

Comment: I'm sorry for not telling it previously! Next time i'll provide it in my question. Thank you for your time and help!